# Java connection to sql server

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

Ok so I have this code:

```
package com.andrewxd.banksystem;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Interface 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1443;user=Andrew;password=andrei23;database=BankSystem");
                System.out.println("test");
                Statement sta = conn.createStatement();
                String Sql = "select * from Clients";
                ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery(Sql);

                System.out.println(rs.next());
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }


}
```

but it gives me this error can somebody help me?:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1443 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
```

I've tried searching but I didn't really understand much.

from what i understand the port is incorrect but how do i find the correct ip/port?

Comment: from what i understand the port is incorrect but how do i find the correct ip/port?

Comment: If you have multiple network interfaces try those IP addresses too.

Comment: This should be in your question, otherwise it can be missed.

Comment: i don't have multiple network interfaces

Comment: Use SSMS to see the listening port at the DB properties

Comment: i checked but i dont see any listening port

Comment: still not working... anymore ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Open SQL Server configuration manager and check to see if the TCP/IP under Network configuration protocols is enabled.

2) Under properties of the SQL serve under Connections check to see if Allow remote connections to this server is allowed.

3) Check to see if you can connect via SSMS and query the database.

4) In SQL Server Configuration manager check to see if the SQL Server Browser service is running. (this is not enabled by default nor is it set up to start up automatically by default).

5) If all those are set up then I would check the firewall.

(For anyone that might come across this the solution was to allow SQL Server and windows authentication)

Comment: tcp/ip status enabled

Comment: Do you have any firewalls on?  Also can you connect via SSMS using that username/password?

Comment: i can't connect to SSMS with Andrew pass andrei23... it gives me error 18456

Comment: Do you have an account to connect to the administrator SQL server to check on the status of the user or can you connect using windows authentication?

Comment: i just connect using windows authentication

Comment: Do either of these work?  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1443;database=BankSystem;Integrated Security=SSPI"); or Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1443;database=BankSystem;Trusted_Connection=True");

Comment: i just needed to unlock access for windows authentication and sql authentication

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your sql server configuration
-has TCP configured, and configured at that IP address.

You can test a couple things:

1. turn off Windows Firewall, from services.msc.
2. try connecting to SQL Server through the IP address,username,pwd the
   application is trying to use. (open enterprise manager, connect, enter IP address etc)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [jtds](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) driver for SQLServer.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Oracle JDBC driver from [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html)

And with your code looking like this:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class OracleJDBC {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        System.out.println("-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------");

        try {

            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }

        System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");

        Connection connection = null;

        try {

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:BankSystem", "Andrew","andrei23");

            } 
        catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }

        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        }
    }

}
```

It should probably work, if not, what does the output look like now ? Still equal to what it was before ? Did you check firewalls ? Connectivity to server allowed ?

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

and i installed ojdbc6.jar to buildpaths

Comment: could it be that your jdbc driver is not in the classpath of your project? did you check preferences of jdbc, like correct path ?

Comment: oh so i need sqljdbc4.jar and ojdbc6.jar now i get it

Comment: but still -------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------
Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!
Connection Failed! Check output console

 IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Comment: which operating system and IDE do you use ?

Comment: windows 8 and eclipse for ide

Comment: if output is like "The Network Adapter could not establish the connection" there could be many reasons for this like: 1.) You are using the wrong URL 2.) The wrong port number or IP address (or DNS host name) was used 3.) The listener is not configured properly 4.) The listener process (service) is not running.  You can re-start it with the "lsnrctl start" command or on Windows by starting the listener service.

Comment: i changed port to 1433 and it gives me this  IO Error: Got minus one from a read call on the line with login infos

Comment: do you have yahoo or skype? and help me a bit with teamviewer?

Comment: You should go though this [link](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.birt.doc%2Fbirt%2Fcon-HowToAddAJDBCDriver.html) step by step to be sure JDBC is configured right. After this in all conscience you should check that you are not attempting to read from a network socket that has been closed by the other hand e.g. configured in a way that connections from your ip will not be accepted. or as i said before check that your JDBC url is correct because you could be attempting to connect to something that isn't a database.

Comment: i cant connect with the user and pass to SSMS it gives me error 18456

Answer (score 0):

The standard port for sqlserver is 1433 and not 1443 as far as I recall it right.